# Why is my Git commit failing with 'duplicate parent' error?

Tags: git

I have a git repo that I have managed to break.

When i commit now, I get the following message:

[image]

Followed by a pop up containing:

```
can't read "old_author": no such variable
can't read "old_author": no such variable
    while executing
"commit_author_reset $old_author"
    (procedure "commit_committree" line 66)
    invoked from within
"commit_committree file431f480 5eed4ce105b8778abd591110ae79e805d412ac2c D:/VP/Vec_repo/.git/GITGUI_EDITMSG"
```

I have tried `git filter-branch`, but to no avail.

The remote repo seems okay, as I have it on another machine.
What has gone wrong with my local repo?

Comment: When you say "I have tried `git filter-branch`...", it's a bit unclear; what were you trying to do with `git filter-branch` and what specific command did you give?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was a failed merge and a bug with the GUI. Using `git merge --abort` on the command line has solved this.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Git-GUI tcl code.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it seems there was a merge that had not completed properly.

Using 'Abort merge' on the git GUI did NOT solve this. However, using bash on the command line and running `git merge --abort` did.